# How to tell Google change the results to the new domain of my blogger website?

Tags: dns, seo, blogger, google-crawlers

I have just moved my site to the new domain (from **math2it.blogspot.com** to [math2it.com](http://www.math2it.com/)). However, I try to search on Google, there still be the old urls with domain "blogspot.com". How can I tell Google to change the results to "math2it.com"?

I have already changed in Webmaster Tools. I also went to [this website](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check) to check the status of redirect. The answer is "Type of redirect: 301 Moved Permanently. Redirected to: math2it.com".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about website administration, not programming. It may be more appropriate on [webmasters.SE].

Comment: @DavidZ: Sorry, I didn't know that there is such site for this purpose. I have seen that there are many questions relating to mine in this site, that's the reason why I pose the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you did everything needed to let Google know about the change.
Give it some time. Google will update your records, but not instantly

Comment: Thanks, I am waiting, hope to get good news from Mr.Google :)